Microsoft Azure Data Factory: Join with "Contains"
I want to join two tables:
Table1



Id
Name




123
Steven Brown


456
Lacie Garrison


789
Tobias Booker



Table2



Names
Country




Steven Brown, Sandra Muller
US


Alex Hampton, Tobias Booker
Canada


Janet Beem
Mexico



Expected Result



Id
Name
Country




123
Steven Brown
US


456
Lacie Garrison



789
Tobias Booker
Canada



I am working with Data Flows at the moment and I can only see that we can do joins or lookups on exact matches, not on contains.
Any ideas are appreciated.

Before joining both the tables, you can do following transformations in table2 to achieve your requirement.

Take source transformation source1 for table1 data.
Similarly, take source transformation source2 for table2 data.
Then take derived column transformation and give the expression for Names column as split(Names,','). This will split the data in the Names column into an array of data.



Then take the flatten transformation and unroll by Names array.



Join the source1 and flatten1 result data using left outer join.


This will give you the expected result
